# Problems with (multiple) jQuery countdowns

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm working on a countdown right now.
The goal is to display multiple countdowns on a page.
One countdown with an interval() is not a problem, but when it gets to two or more countdowns it will only display the last countdown.

Countdown structure:

1. Grab the unix timestamp from `<div value"..."> <div>`
2. Turn unix timestamp with jQuery to a nice countdown.
3. Display all countdowns on the page with `.html()` or `.text()`

Hope you can help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/be89dwno/

Comment: You can't just put a `value` attribute on a `<div>` element like that... Use at least an hidden input no ? Or a `data-` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
$(".timestamp").text(function(k){
    return seconds[k];
});
```

with:

```
$(this).text(seconds[k]);
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/be89dwno/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to keep the original value you can also use something like this:

```
$(".timestamp").each(function() {
    var timestamp_value = $(this).attr("value");
    var new_value =  timestamp_value - 1;
    //change how you want your time look like below
    var new_value_text = new_value.toString();
    $(this).attr("value", new_value);
    $(this).html(new_value_text);
});
```

put it in a function and then use setInterval. Demo link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/x6htakaw/